# WPF Dragging causes renderer to stop

Tags: .net, wpf, performance, debugging

I'm having a problem with my WPF app, where any sort of drag operation stops the UI from updating. The issue seems periodic, as in, the item drags, stops, drags again, stops, etc. in 2 second intervals. It's affecting all controls, including scroll bars.

If checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104224/how-do-you-troubleshoot-wpf-ui-problems) question as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122857/wpf-transparent-borders-causes-the-ui-to-stop-redrawing) one, and it doesn't seem to be caused by window transparencies. I'm running Win7 x64 with .NET 3.5sp1.

Does anyone know what might be causing this, or a way of figuring out what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone cares, I found out what was going on.

We had an effect over the entire app that could blur the window when performing a long operation. This effect was always there and a trigger would cause the effect to change from clear to blurry.

Because the effect was always 'on' WPF had to do more work when rendering the app. By changing the xaml of the main window so that the effect was only set when needed, and removed afterwards, the dragging issue disappeared.